# Mono: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, linux, vb.net, mono

I keep getting this error half way through my application. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10. The assemblies are in the same directory as the application, just like in the debug folder on my windows desktop. I was actually able to run it this way on my RasberryPi. I did load the assemblies into the mono GAC. However, the actual assemblies are named all lower case, while in the error it has some uppercase letters:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at ASGI.Module1.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
  at ASGI.Module1.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Did you copy the Windows version of MySql.Data.dll to Linux? If so, it is very likely to fail as the Windows version might not be prepared for Mono. http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html 
Did you try to change the "Select Platform:" to .NET & Mono and use that copy?